# Circle pack layout using nest() and rollup

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a circle pack graph using `nest()` and `.rollup`. I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(undefined,undefined)"
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute r="NaN"
```

I want the circles to be sized according to the number of companies in each country. I'm attempting to adapt Mike Bostock's [Flare](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530) circle-pack example.

If anyone could point me in the direction of any information, I'd be very grateful.

JS code:

```
var diameter = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d");

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(2,2)");

//Get data
d3.json("data/countriesNested.php", function(error, data){

  var submissionsByCountry = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
      .key(function(d) { return d.Organisation; })
      .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
      .entries(data);    

  var node = svg.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
      .data(pack.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.cx + "," + d.cy + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name + (d.children ? "" : ": " + format(d.size)); });

      node.append("circle")
          .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

</script>
```

Data file (from MySQL using PHP script):

```
    [
  {
    "Country":"USA",
    "ID":4,
    "Organisation":"Company 1"
  },
  {
    "Country":"USA",
    "ID":5,
    "Organisation":"Company 2"
  },
  {
    "Country":"USA",
    "ID":6,
    "Organisation":"Company 3"
  },
 {
    "Country":"FRANCE",
    "ID":19,
    "Organisation":"Company 4"
  },
  {
    "Country":"FRANCE",
    "ID":24,
    "Organisation":"Company 5"
  },
  {
    "Country":"GERMANY",
    "ID":10,
    "Organisation":"Company 6"
  },
  {
    "Country":"ITALY",
    "ID":7,
    "Organisation":"Company 7"
  },
  .....
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code that need to be fixed:

1. You need to set the accessor functions for children and values on your pack layout:

   ```
   var pack = d3.layout.pack()
     .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
     .children(function(d) {
       return d.values;  // accessor for children
     })
     .value(function(d) {
       return d.values;  // accessor for values
     });
   ```
2. Your `d3.nest()` returns an array but `d3.pack()` requires you to supply a root *object* containing the hierarchy. You have to create a root object and put your nested array inside:

   ```
   var countryRoot = {
       key: "root",
       values: submissionsByCountry
   };
   ```
3. In your code you nest your data into `submissionsByCountry` but you are not using this variable anywhere else. So you obviously have to refer to it when binding data to your `svg`. This is accomplished by the above mentioned root object which is later on bound to the `svg`.

   ```
   var node = svg.datum(countryRoot).selectAll(".node")
   ```
4. The attributes the pack layout is adding to your data nodes include values `x` and `y`, whereas you refered to them as `cx` and `cy` which are attributes to `<svg:circle>` but are not present in your data. Hence, you got your `transform="translate(undefined,undefined)"` error messages. You should use these attributes as such:

   ```
   .attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
   });
   ```

I put together a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ycPSdLwVnbu62JwO9d0?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

So, you want a parent circle (let's call it the world), with child circles representing each country sized with a count of entries in your JSON array?

```
d3.json("data/countriesNested.php", function(error, data) {

    var submissionsByCountry = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.Country;
      })
      .rollup(function(leaves) {
        return leaves.length;
      })
      .entries(data);

    var root = {
      "key": "world",
      "children": submissionsByCountry
    };

    ...
```

This will give you something closely resembling the `flare.json`.

Next, you need to give d3 the right [accessor](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#value) for your circle size.

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.values; //<-- this comes from your roll-up and is the count.
  });
```

Finally it looks like you changed the example code to access non-exist `cx` and `cy` attributes in the resulting nodes data:

```
var node = svg.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
  .data(pack.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node";
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; //<-- this is .x, .y
  });
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ysdyynglpqD8tXTSd6X?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much for this! The accessor function was my biggest stumbling block. I gave the "accepted answer" vote to the solution above as it goes a small step further and nests the organizations within their respective countries, within the 'world', though essentially, both solutions answer my question. Thanks again - I appreciate your help.